# How do I automatically check for '.only' calls accidentally left in Mocha specs?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, eslint

I occasionally forget to remove `.only` calls from my Mocha specs before pushing spec changes. Doing so obviously affects test coverage, which requires addressing the failure(s). I'd like to catch these before I push changes, ideally as part of the linting process with ESLint and with minimal effort.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the [`mocha/no-exclusive-tests`](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/blob/master/docs/rules/no-exclusive-tests.md) rule, part of the `eslint-plugin-mocha` plugin.  It fails if it finds any `describe.only` or `it.only`.  Very useful!

From the [docs:](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha#install-and-configure)

> This plugin requires ESLint 4.0.0 or later.
>
> ```
> npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-mocha
> ```
>
> Then add a reference to this plugin and selected rules in your eslint config:
>
> ```
> {
>   "plugins": [
>     "mocha"
>   ],
>   "rules": {
>     "mocha/no-exclusive-tests": "error"
>   }
> }
> ```

There is also a `mocha/no-skipped-tests` if you want to prevent `it.skip` or `xit` from being committed too.  However, I find that `.skip` is sometimes valid, so I find it best to just prevent `.only`.

That plugin also has a ton of other useful checks, so be sure to read their docs!

Answer (score 3):

You have a `--forbid-only` parameter to be passed when executing mocha which will make your tests fail.

You have also the `--forbid-pending`.

Here from the official doc:

> **--forbid-only**  causes test marked with only to fail the suite
>
> **--forbid-pending** causes pending tests and test marked with skip to fail the suite

Answer (score 1):

Another package doing just this is [eslint-plugin-no-only-tests](https://github.com/levibuzolic/eslint-plugin-no-only-tests).

Alternatively, this can now be done by following built-in ESLint rules, but they will highlight the whole function body of the callback as error as well:

```json
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",
  {
    "selector": "CallExpression[callee.object.type='Identifier'][callee.object.name='it'][callee.property.type='Identifier'][callee.property.name='only']",
    "message": "Do not commit it.only. Use it instead."
  },
  {
    "selector": "CallExpression[callee.object.type='Identifier'][callee.object.name='describe'][callee.property.type='Identifier'][callee.property.name='only']",
    "message": "Do not commit describe.only. Use describe instead."
  }
]
```

For an exclusion of `fdescribe` and `fit` the following can be used:

```json
"no-restricted-globals": [
  "error",
  {
    "name": "fdescribe",
    "message": "Do not commit fdescribe. Use describe instead."
  },
  {
    "name": "fit",
    "message": "Do not commit fit. Use it instead."
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a simple bash script with the `grep` command, added to the `package.json` scripts section like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint:only": "RESULT=\"$(grep -rHn '[.]only\\|[.]skip' spec/ --color=always)\"; if [ -n \"$RESULT\" ]; then printf \"Oops! You left a few things in your specs! \n\n${RESULT}\n\n\"; fi",
  "lint": "eslint --ext js src config scripts bin config server; yarn lint:only"
  ...
}
```

In a nutshell, this checks the `spec/` directory for anything matching `.only` or `.skip` and outputs the filename + line if anything offending is found. Color is added for clarity and the script is run as part of linting with ESLint and Yarn.